# Show specific content for each div using Fancybox,

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to load a specific sibling for each div using fancybox.

E.g:

```
<div id ="content">
<div class="item1">
<div class="pop-ups"><span>click</span></div>
<div class="hidden"><span>content for item 1</span></div>
</div>
<div class="item2">
<div class="pop-ups"><span>click</span></div>
<div class="hidden"><span>content for item 2</span></div>
</div>
<div class="item3">
<div class="pop-ups"><span>click</span></div>
<div class="hidden"><span>content for item 3</span></div>
</div>
<div class="item4">
<div class="pop-ups"><span>click</span></div>
<div class="hidden"><span>content for item 4</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried to do the config using the property Content, but not got it, is  it possible to get each hidden for each specific item ?

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: what js are you using? .... how are you binding fancybox (and to what selector)?

Comment: I am using jquery/1.7.2 with fancybox 1.3.4,

Comment: got it, but we were talking about your custom script

Comment: mcpDESIGNS I tried to make a trigger or bind the event click, I am thinking in a way to know the siblings or something like that but did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
$(function(){
   $("div.pop-ups span").click(function(){
      $.fancybox({ content: $(this).parent().next().html() });
   });
});
```

This will show the content of relevant div in fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

You can call this function to open some specific div content in a fancybox.

```
    function OpenDiv(divIDtoopen) //eg. divIDtoopen= #divID //# is must to be prepended to divID for selection 
    {
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $.fancybox.open(
                {
                    href: divtoopen
                }
                );
        }
        );
    }
```